# DRF (beginner question ) : How to change globally date format in setting.py

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Please don't consider it a duplicate because  I have tried all the solutions and it did not work for me. Maybe I just miss something. 
So to change the date Format I add the following command in the setting.py but none of them worked.

I first tried :

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # "DATE_INPUT_FORMATS": "%d-%m-%Y", doesn't works
    'DATE_INPUT_FORMATS': ["%d.%m.%Y"],
}
```

then just :

`'DATE_INPUT_FORMATS': ["%d.%m.%Y"]`

or

`DATE_INPUT_FORMATS : ( "%d.%m.%Y")`

or

`DATE_INPUT_FORMATS :  "%d.%m.%Y"`

I have been looking in [the documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#date_format) . I don't know what I am missing ?

I got this error : 
`django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“11.11.1111” value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.']`

thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Have you hardcoded this value anywhere? `11.11.1111`

Comment: No , I did not harcoded anything .  the message error  is when I save some object  from the Django shell , I use the code from the official Tutorial ( part 1 )

Comment: Ok, Which object and what are its values?

Comment: I do it like that via the django shell ( I saw it in the tutorial )                                                                                                                                 
from payload.models import Payload
from payload.serializers import PayloadSerializer
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser

test = Payload(first_name = "remi", last_name= "toudic" , email = "remitoudic@gmail.com", birthday= "11.11.1111" )
test.save()

Comment: sorry for the formatting ...

Comment: Is there any format specified in Payload model for birthday?

Comment: No birthday  has no specified format given  in model.py   =>  birthday = models.DateField(null=True) . In the serializer.py birthday = serializers.DateField(format="%d.%m.%Y", required=False, read_only=True)

Comment: Try this  `birthday = DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)`

Comment: THANK you for help . models. DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS) => Error  , with models.DateField( settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)  I could makemigrations and migrate but did not change anything  in the default format :(